# Javascript interrupt Page request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that sends a request to the server. On the server we then send a synchronous request to a third party web API. Because of the call to the web API we never have complete control over how long our server side processing will take. So, what I would like to do is write a javascript function that will interrupt this page request and forward the user to an error page after so much time. So my javascript would look a little like this.

```
function onSubmit() {
   var oneMinute = (60 * 1000);
   setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("http://errorPage.html"); }, oneMinute);
   return true;
}
```

The problem is that even when the timeout method is executed the page still waits for a response from the server before redirecting to the error page. Is there a way to interrupt the page request so that it doesn't wait until a response is received before redirecting to the error page?

Comment: Have you considered making the 3rd party request ASYNC, and having your server return an error after _n_ seconds?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good question. We have considered it, but we really need the result from the 3rd party web API to give our user a meaningful response so it really isn't an option for us.

Comment: I think @paislee's idea was to implement the timeout in the server code which will probably have more powerful facilities for handling this than Javascript. So you do 1. the AJAX call that waits for a response from the server; 2. the server does an async call to the web API; 3. the server waits for a response to the call with a timeout of at most 30 seconds; 4. the server returns either the web API results or an error to the AJAX call.

Comment: @Inerdial yes. thx for clarifying. you basically cap the initial request at _n_ seconds, no funny business for the client.

Comment: I agree guys, and when we rewrite this system that will be the approach we probably take. Unfortunately, for the time being we are just trying to put a band-aid onto an ASP.Net WebForms page with UpdatePanels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this , not sure whether it will work in all the browsers.

```
function onSubmit() {
   var oneMinute = (60 * 1000);
   setTimeout(function(){ 
        if($.browser.msie){
            document.execCommand('Stop');
        }
        else{//Other browsers
            window.stop(); 
        }
        window.location.replace("http://errorPage.html"); 
   }, oneMinute);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: That is another issue, but the request is stopped.

Comment: The above code answers my original question and so I marked it as correct. However, as I looked into the issue more I learned that I had incorrect assumptions in the original question. window.location.replace will automatically redirect to another page without waiting for the response from the original page request. The reason it looked to me as though it wasn't was because when testing on my local machine I had my server set up to handle only one request at a time and so the page wouldn't redirect until the original request was processed.